# HSQL SQLTool cant connect

Tags: java, hsqldb, sqltools

I get the following:

```
java -jar ./sqltool/sqltool.jar inlineRc=url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://192.168.99.100/test,user=sa
Please enter password for sa!:  
SqlTool v. 5337.
Can't connect to jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://192.168.99.100/test for user "org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver"! 
Reason: org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
```

I am using sqltool.jar in version 2.3.3. Anybody got a workaround or explaination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running SQLTool in this manner requires the hsqldb.jar to be in the same directory as the sqltool.jar.

The error message indicates it cannot find the HSQLDB's JDBC driver, which is in the hsqldb.jar.